GM_xmlhttpRequest - injected: Refused to connect to "https://...": URL is not permitted
I use the latest Firefox, Tampermonkey and do some cross site scripting. And this script is working for multiple people just fine. But suddenly for 1 and only 1 person I get this error message:
injected: Refused to connect to "https://...": URL is not permitted

The odd thing is, that this only happens to url.com/?article=123 but works fine for url.com/?article=456
[edit]
Yes, the 1:1 copy of the request with the same article Body works perfectly for me.
[/edit]

The request is just absolutely identical except the article ID.
Okay, I did not use the // @connect directive of Tampermonkey. But I never have done this for every cross site scripting thingy and it always worked like a charm and this only happens for this 1 user for this 1 page. He has basically a 1:1 copy of my firefox profile. Everything is the same. So what is the situation with this error?
Is it indeed related to the @connect directive? But if so, why is it working 99.9999% of the time without that and for exclusively CORS applications?
Does anyone have some good documentation on what causes this error specifically and predictably?

Okay the solution is stupid, as it is not well documented.
You can do this:
try { await your GM_xmlhttpRequest }
catch (error) { handleFetchErrors(error, "Some unique name for your website") }

some code...

  function handleFetchErrors(error, targetPageName="")
  {
    if (error && error.error && error.error.includes("Refused to connect to"))
    {
      if (error.error.includes("URL is blacklisted"))
      {
        writeTeletype(`Error: ${targetPageName} not permitted by Tampermonkey. Remove it from blacklist!`, "e");
        writeTeletype("Go to Tampermonkey > Settings > Security > Negative List", "i");
      }
      else if (error.error.includes("URL is not permitted:") && error.error.includes("@connects") && error.error.includes("strict mode enabled"))
      {
        writeTeletype(`Error: ${targetPageName} not permitted by Tampermonkey. Strict mode enabled!`, "e");
        writeTeletype("Go to Tampermonkey > Settings > Security > @connect check  \"Ask\" or \"Always Ask\"", "i");
      }
      else if (error.error.includes("URL is not permitted"))
      {
        writeTeletype(`Error: ${targetPageName} not permitted by Tampermonkey.`, "e");
        writeTeletype("Tampermonkey settings are broken. Consider reinstalling it (or factory default).", "i");
        writeTeletype("Tip: If you just where asked for permissions and missed the countdown:", "i");
        writeTeletype("Open the script overview, select the script and load script defaults.", "i");
      }
      else if (error.error.includes("This domain is not a part of the @connect list"))
      {
        writeTeletype(`Error: ${targetPageName} is not correctly allowed.`, "e");
        writeTeletype("Contact script author to repair the @connect list.", "i");
      }
      else if (error.error.includes("Request was blocked by the user"))
      {
        writeTeletype(`Error: Request to ${targetPageName} blocked by you!`, "e");
        writeTeletype("When asked again, you need to allow it. Consider \"Always allow this domain\"", "i");
        writeTeletype("If you accidentally clicked \"Never Ask again\":", "i");
        writeTeletype("Open the script overview, select the script and load script defaults.", "i");
      }
      return;
    }
    writeTeletype(`Error: Getting ${targetPageName} Data failed. Check dev console (F12) and report the error there.`, "e");
    console.log(error);
  }

TLDR:
It is caused by tampermonkey permissions and there are a lot of different errors possible. Above code example handles a lot of them. It assumes, that you have a "writeTeletype(message, type)" function to report this to the user. Just replace with your own reporting function as needed.
